# How to set a property value to auto increment in visual studio lightswitch 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

i want to set a property value in a table to default auto increment,but their are no options to do so in lightswitch2012 to my knowledge which is given that i recently started learning lightswitch,very light.

ok heres the real problem,this is the table

[customer][id,customer_id,name]

i want to set customer_id by default to id unless it is manually changed to different value.

how to acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Entity designer make your Customer_ID not required. 
Write Code for Customers_Inserted.

Then, check to see if the Customer_ID is null. If it is, copy the ID field to it.

```
private void Customers_Inserted(Customer entity)
{
    if (entity.Customer_ID == null) {
        entity.Customer_ID = entity.ID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there is no "auto-increment" data type available in LightSwitch. The *ID* property auto-increments, but that's a special case, handled by LightSwitch.

If you were attaching to an *external SQL database*, if you added a column that was an *Integer Identity* column, although it'll just appear as an *Integer* property in LightSwitch, it would still auto-increment because that's actually done in the SQL database itself.

The problem with all auto-increment properties is that you won't get the actual value until the record is saved.

Can I ask why you need an auto-increment property?

Comment: i have a "customer" table with id(auto generated), customer_id, name and so on.some customers have presetid's and for others it has to be auto generated.so when inserting a new customer row its customer_id is by default set to id of the row.if customer has preset id the customer_id can be manually edited to set preset id.

Comment: is there any way i could do that?

Comment: No, you can't mix & match auto-increment & setting the ID manually.

Comment: i understand i cant set id manually but what if i have another property which by default has value of id and unless manually set to other value?

Comment: You can't **manually** set the value of an _auto-incrementing_ property, so that property would have to be a **non auto-incrementing property**. But in LightSwitch, you shouldn't be attempting to use manual ID's, you should be using relationships between tables, & setting the resulting navigation properties with a retrieved entity object, you don't set ID's manually in LightSwitch.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve, but if you are using either a table or a grid, and you want to set the values for various entities for each new row your user adds (like customer_id = id, etc.), you can use the _Changed method and Add event to programmatically set any of the new row entities.

If this is along the lines of what you're looking for, watch Beth Massi's video [How Do I: Copy Data from One Row into a New Row?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh307862)  You should be able to adapt her code to accomplish what you have in mind I think.